# mavn command showing success but .ear file not getting generated

Tags: maven, tibco

I am trying to build a .ear file of tibco bw6 application, below is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tibco.bw</groupId>
  <artifactId>ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool.application.parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
   <!-- <module>../sm.baseSchemas</module> 
    <module>../sm.cleClient</module>
    <module>../sm.enterpriseSchemas</module>
    <module>../sm.jmsEsb</module>
    <module>../ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool</module>
    <module>../ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool.application</module>-->
  </modules>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
   
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <finalName>ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool.application</finalName>
        <version>6</version>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <modules>
            <module>../sm.baseSchemas</module> 
            <module>../sm.cleClient</module>
            <module>../sm.enterpriseSchemas</module>
            <module>../sm.jmsEsb</module>
            <module>../ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool</module>
            <module>../ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool.application</module>-->
        </modules>
          <!-- Add your project modules here -->
          <ejbModule>
            <groupId>com.tibco.bw</groupId>
            <artifactId>ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool.application.parent</artifactId>
            <bundleFileName>my-ejb-module.jar</bundleFileName>
          </ejbModule>
          <webModule>
            <groupId>com.tibco.bw</groupId>
            <artifactId>ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool.application.parent</artifactId>
            <contextRoot>/my-web-module</contextRoot>
          </webModule>
          <!-- Add more modules as needed -->
        <modules>
            <module>../sm.baseSchemas</module> 
            <module>../sm.cleClient</module>
            <module>../sm.enterpriseSchemas</module>
            <module>../sm.jmsEsb</module>
            <module>../ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool</module>
            <module>../ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool.application</module>-->
        </modules>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency> 
         <groupId>com.tibco.bw</groupId>
         <artifactId>sm.baseSchemas</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
         <groupId>com.tibco.bw</groupId>
         <artifactId>sm.cleClient</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
         <groupId>com.tibco.bw</groupId>
         <artifactId>sm.enterpriseSchemas</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
         <groupId>com.tibco.bw</groupId>
         <artifactId>sm.jmsEsb</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
         <groupId>com.tibco.bw</groupId>
         <artifactId>pp.customXpathFunctions</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
      </dependencies> 
</project>
```

after running command "mvn clean install" the log shoiwng success but the .ear file is not getting generated.

```
C:\Users\ndey\Downloads\ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool-dev\ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool-dev\src\ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool.application.parent>mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --< com.tibco.bw:ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool.application.parent >--
[INFO] Building ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool.application.parent 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool.application.parent ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.289 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-28T09:02:14+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

is there anything i am missing in pom file? the .ear file should be generated and stored in target folder, my local has already installed maven not getting any error in log also

Comment: `<packaging>pom</packaging>` - you either need to change packaging to `ear` or assign `maven-ear-plugin` goal to `package` phase.

Comment: In general having a multi module builds is fine but defining the ear plugin for executin in the parent is simply wrong... make a separate module and define the needed ejbs/wars etc. in the module as dependency and define the packaging `ear` and run your build from root... that will work... but based on those things like `module>../..` your setup looks wrong...